# LG G Pad 70 and Pine Phone

Tags: touchpad

So grateful to have a space like this with folks like you to help educate newbies like myself. I've inherited an LG G Pad 70 and just purchased a Pine Phone. I want to stop all android use and jump right in to Ubuntu. What apps do i need to download to install Ubuntu on both devices? Do I download the desktop or the touch for the LG Gpad70? What installer do you suggest for the LG Gpad70?

There are so many how to videos for the pine phone but I seem to run into a combination of problems like dead links or missing steps. On the other hand I'm really new to this OS and am probably a tad bit overwhelmed. I have made 2 attempts at installing and or setting up Pine phone but as I've stated.... I'm missing steps or something. Please guide me to a step by step article or video regarding the best  Ubuntu version to download and installer for the pine phone?
Thank you, A

Comment: If you consider the answer helpful please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch is no longer officially supported (i.e. supported by Canonical).

[There's a community fork that still is under development.](https://ubports.com/)

However, before you get your hopes high here's a reality check:

1. It's NOT for newbies.
2. It's not an "app" that you can install from a store with a couple of taps. It requires flashing an entire ROM (OS image) using tools that aren't intuitive or easy.
3. Only a small set of devices, mostly old ones, have a ready made image that you can flash and use right away instead of Android.

Please check the list of currently [supported devices](https://ubports.com/en/supported-products) before anything else. The link include information about the supported devices as well as specific instructions for each one. Please check the other devices and their status.

Comment: Thanks Changanauto! You are correct on the "steps" you've listed above for the new os. I've done the research, hence my request for suggestions for best step by step and installer(s). Plus we all need to start some where when learning anything new. So why not learn as I go. Better to learn the correct or best methods rather than fumbaling along like i was. So i thought id ask some pro's in here.  However, I've found a wiki to help with pine phone now just need the LG G Pad. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Indeed, the Pinephone is not only supported but a sort of flagship / showcase model for alternative Linux based OSes because it has been designed from the ground up with as much openness or transparency as possible. The LG one sits in the opposite side of the spectrum, pretty much everything inside is proprietary, locked bootloader, etc. Even after unlocking it, required for flashing, you can only use a generic basic ROM. The predicted result is many things not working due to the lack of proprietary drivers. Good luck.